# Problem with MySQL Select OR Statement? Driving me nuts

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm creating a WP plugin that will store settings in a custom table and retrieve them based on page ID or category ID, and if it's within a time frame. The date selection bit is working fine; the problem persists when the date selection part of the statement is removed.

The problem is that each *select...or* statement works *on it's own* but when I connect them using brackets and an OR selector it only pulls category. This is identical code I'm using, with the date stuff (that works) removed for clarity:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM {$tablename}
WHERE (
      ( start_id = {$postid} OR ( start_id < {$postid} AND stop_id >= {$postid} ) AND scope = 'post' )
   OR ( start_id = {$categoryid} OR ( start_id < {$categoryid} AND stop_id >= {$categoryid} ) AND scope = 'category' )
 )
AND ( ...date selector... )";
```

When I use this code it only pulls the category entry, even if there is a post entry that matches the criteria (that it should grab first). If I remove the category selector, it pulls the post entry just fine. There is no interference among start/stop_IDs from different rows; already checked that.

The basic table structure is this...note that some fields are null because the user will be able to specify either a range or a single page or category ID.

```
ID    start_id    stop_id    scope       storedsettings
1     40          45         post        ...
2     50          NULL       category    ...
3     67          70         category    ...
4     71          NULL       post        ...
```

Thank you very much for any insight into this problem!

EDIT to address some comments: (1) @JESUS: The insertion is very specific and won't allow duplicates based on ID, so it's always pulling one row; (2) @IVANIVAN: What you mean is operator precedence? OR is factored before AND, so I group the AND and then use that as the other side of the OR. Or am I misunderstanding your answer? Thx!

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for the heads up but I handle it properly inside Wordpress. This is very stripped down code so you can understand my problem.

Comment: @RalphTheWonderLlama Interesting. Your query seems right. Just for test purpopes: What happens if you remove the ( ...date selector... ) part?

Comment: @EvE Makes no difference at all. It's got me totally baffled.

Comment: You've sub-expressions of the form `(x OR (y1 AND y2) AND z)` aka `(x OR y AND z)`. Are you sure you don't need to be more explicit in forcing your evaluation order? Guessing it needs to be `((x OR y) AND z)` aka `((x OR (y1 AND y2)) AND z)`

Comment: Following on with @Uueerdo 's comment - when I do complicated choices like this I always over-parenthesize and use them in sufficient quantities and the right locations to make everything absolutely specific.

Comment: What criteria are you using where it can pull more than 1 record through but it's only showing 1?

Comment: @ivanivan and [at]Jesus I've edited the question to address your comments. Thx!

Comment: @RiggsFolly parameterised statements won't work real well here by the looks - you can't parameterise a table name. Perhaps the OP can safely construct a parameterised statement with only the table name as a variable injection, but they still need decent checks to prevent an SQLi attack.

Comment: To add to myself and @ivanivan, I always explicitly force evaluation order with parenthesis whenever mixing AND and OR because: (1) honestly, I can't be bothered to remember their precedence, and (2) I want the "next guy" _(most often me a year or so later)_ to know the order I intended.

Comment: @Uueerdo wise words. will doing that much extra factoring in the select statement have a noticeable effect on speed? I’m thinking no, but I’m trying to keep this as trim as possible.

Comment: @RalphTheWonderLlama `AND` is evaluated before `OR`. `x OR (y1 AND y2) AND z` === `x OR (y1 AND y2 AND z)` but you probably want `(x OR y1 AND y2) AND z`

Comment: @RalphTheWonderLlama `OR` generally hurts more than any parenthesis, and performance is kind of secondary in these situations; since without parenthesis, it is not even the correct condition to use.